# asp.net panel statement

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

am having trouble with visible attribute of an asp.net panel. Basically I have a page that calls a database table and returns the results in a detailsview. However, some of the values that are returned are null and if so I need to hide the image thats next to it.

I am using a panel to determine whether to hide or show the image but am having trouble with the statement:

visible='<%# Eval("addr1") <> DBNull.Value %>'

I have tried these as well:

visible='<%# Eval("addr1") <> DBNull.Value %>'

visible='<%# IIf(Eval("addr1") Is DbNull.Value, "False","True") %>'

When I use these I get the error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Any help on what the syntax should be would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code pls?  Are you doing anything client-side?

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax says VB.NET, but you're compiler says C# (the CS* compiler error). Since I trust your compiler more:

```
Visible='<%# Eval("addr1") != DBNull.Value %>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate Databinding (for many reason, including this), Whenever I have an overly complex expression to bind to.   I alawys declare it in the code behind and call on it to do the dirty work.

Something like

```
> visible='<%# GetIsVisible(Eval("addr1"))  %>'
```

Then you define your 'GetIsVisible' method to take a single object as a parameter.  I'll leave that up to you, since you are using VB and I'll surely butcher it.

**Edit: Just noticed you say you are using C#**
If its in C# you'll need to use the != operator, there is no <> operator in C#.

```
> visible='<%# Eval("addr1") <> DBNull.Value %>'
```

needs to be something like

```
> visible='<%# Eval("addr1") != DBNull.Value %>'
```

Also I would prob just use [Convert.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx)

```
> visible='<%# !Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("addr1")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: visible='<%# (Eval("addr1") is DbNull.Value? "False":"True") %>'

the proper syntax for iif is (condition?if true this value : if false this value) assuming your using c#

Answer (score 0):

Erm...

Does this work?

```
visible='<%= IIf(Eval("addr1") Is DbNull.Value, "False","True") %>'
```

Or do you in fact have a semicolon at the end, like this (you shouldn't have BTW)

```
visible='<%# IIf(Eval("addr1") Is DbNull.Value, "False","True"); %>'
```

Comment: "False" and "True" are strings. Visible wants a Boolean, so you'd leave off the quotes (of course, Iif returns an object, so you'd probably have to cast as well).

Answer (score 0):

More stabs in the dark, try this

```
visible="<%# IIf(Eval('addr1') Is DbNull.Value, 'False','True') %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bringing an old thread back up, just wanted to say:

visible='<%# !Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("addr1")) %>'

this worked - LEGEND

thanks all